# What happens when I cast null to another class

Tags: c#, resharper

I have some code in a library method that looks like this:

```
public static WebDavProviderBase GetProvider(string relativePath)
{
  if (relativePath == null)
    return (WebDavProviderBase) null;
  if (relativePath.Length == 0)
    return (WebDavProviderBase) new DefaultProvider();
  WebDavProviderBase returnProvider = (WebDavProviderBase) null;
  if ((int) relativePath[0] == 47)
    relativePath = relativePath.Substring(1);
  WebDavProviderBase.GetRootProvider().MapPath(relativePath, out returnProvider);
  return returnProvider;
}
```

And when I use the code, it looks like this:

```
WebDavProviderBase provider = WebDavProviderBase.GetProvider(relativePath);

if (provider == null)
{
    //Do something
}
```

However, Resharper (10 Ultimate) complains about the null-check, and says this is a superfluous check, because provider can never be null.

Is Resharper wrong, or will `(WebDavProviderBase)null` return a new WebDavProviderBase?

Screenshot as requested:
[image: Provider can not be null message]

**UPDATE:**
After getting help from Jebs answer below, this is the conclusion:
relativePath can not be null when GetProvider gets called, because the application will allready have crashed because of the relativePath.Lenght check further up in the code. (See screenshot)

Comment: Reshaper is wrong. Or the code you posted was too simplified. Note that I *don't* get that Resharper warning (and I'm using R#10.0.2). So I suspect you haven't posted a correct repro.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full thirdparty library code in case it makes any difference. Also note that this code is in a thirdparty dll.

Comment: Just realized that it's not Resharper giving the error, it's Visual Studio 2015 Professional. Updated question again.

Comment: what happens if you write `WebDavProviderBase.GetProvider(null);` instead?

Comment: As per the updated question information, I have deleted my answer as I'm not familiar enough with Visual Studio's default warnings, especially the 2015 version, since I use the 2012 version with Resharper.

Comment: Please post the complete error message that you get. Also, if possible, please provide a [mcve] which only uses classes that we have access to.

Comment: Gez, I'm sorry. It is Resharper generating the error.

Comment: @andreasnico A screenshot might be helpful

Comment: Screenshot with complete errormessage added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by addressing your concluding questions. There are two of them, merged into one (please try to avoid that), so I'll split them up and answer one at a time:

> Is Resharper wrong...?

<strike>Yes.</strike> Well, maybe... More on that later.

> ... or will `(WebDavProviderBase)null` return a new WebDavProviderBase?

No.

---

> Visual Studio 2015 Professional ... says this is a superfluous check, because provider can never be null.

This is perhaps only coincidentally connected to the question you asked, but it might be helpful to explain what I think is happening here anyway. VS2015 might be performing some form of deduction, inferring that when `relativePath` is non-null, the return value will also be non-null. There are two prerequisites here:

- Can VS2015 deduce that `relativePath` is non-null, just by looking at the code you've written? If you've assigned that to a constant value, the answer is a definite "yes", for example. **UPDATE**: The `.ToString()` method is guaranteed to return a string or raise an exception, so the compiler can most likely deduce that `relativePath` is always non-null here.
- Can VS2015 deduce that non-null `relativePath` values correspond to non-null `GetProvider` return values? This involves more complex functionality on behalf of the compiler, but it's not outside of the realm of compilation nonetheless... If the compiler can follow your logic and deduce that `null` can't possibly be returned, then it can safely tell you that your `null` checks are erroneous.

Comment: I've tried to track down the creation of relativePath, but I can't really get to the end of the real creation.

Comment: @andreasnico Deductions don't just happen based on values, but also based on operations... For example, if there are any `String` methods (e.g. `String.Length`) used upon `relativePath` prior to `WebDavProviderBase.GetProvider` being called, this would be enough for such an inference to pass, as an exception would be thrown at that point which would interrupt execution before the method is called.

Comment: Ah, so relativePath.Length (se recently added screenshot) will of course crash the whole thing before GetProvider gets called, and hence relativePath can not be null when GetProvider is called. Thank you!

Comment: @andreasnico Yes, but more importantly `request.Url.ToString()` will return a string (which is non-null) or raise an exception. The process of deduction can continue from there.

Comment: mm, isnt request.Url.ToString() only setting the string url-variable. It's notting to do with relativeUrl

Comment: @andreasnico rather than figure out where it's assigned, try playing with it.  What happens if you add a line before `WebDavProviderBase provider = WebDavProviderBase.GetProvider(relativePath);` saying `relativePath = null;`?

Comment: @andreasnico No. `Object.ToString` constructs a string. You could override that method to `return null;`, which would achieve the same result as John's suggestion above. Practically speaking, I guess this contradicts my statements above (that it always returns non-null) however, I see no reason that people would override this method to return `null`.

Comment: ... and even if they did, the compiler could notice that the method is overrided and adjust it's deductions accordingly.

Comment: I think you are confusing these two codelines: string url = this.RemoveTrailingSlash(request.Url.ToString());
                string relativePath = this.RemoveTrailingSlash(request.Path);

Comment: @andreasnico Indeed. My bad... There are probably string methods (or array index) used in `this.RemoveTrailingSlash` that would throw an exception if `request.Path` were `null`... Perhaps you could add some `null` checks and `return null` into that, and see how that changes things?

Comment: It's a little complex to get the exact situations i want in this app, so I think I'll just leave it at that, but thanks a lot for your help!